# DbWriteTable() writing multiple copies of my data to SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite

I've been doing processing data with R that results in a data frame of typically 4860 observations. I write that to a Results table in a SQLite database like this:

```
db = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname=DATAFILE)
dbWriteTable(db, "Results", my_dataframe, append = TRUE)
dbDisconnect(db)
```

Then I process some more data and later write it to the same table using this same code.

The problem is, every now and again, what's written to my SQLite file is some multiple of the 4860 records I expect. Just now it was 19448 (exactly 4X the 4860 records that I can see in RStudio are in my data frame).

This seems such a random problem. As I know the data frame contents is correct, I feel as though the problem must be in my use of dbWriteTable(). Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If it was me, I'd wonder what influence `append` had on the problem. Applying [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) to the visible code,  the `dbWriteTable` is executing multiple times on the same dataframe.

Comment: It makes sense, @DinoCoderSaurus, of course. Particularly since writing to a fresh table in the database (as opposed to appending) works fine. What has flummoxed me is how appending works correctly for 10 or so iterations, then doesn't.

Comment: If "_appending works correctly for 10 or so iterations, then doesn't._", some state has changed (or some state is not detected or not detected properly).

Comment: Surprisingly, modifying the DbWriteTable() call just to use a different table name in the same database, works as expected, with the correct number of observations saved.

Comment: Begs the question: is there another `dbWriteTable` in the script?

Comment: Sadly, no. I'm literally running my code manually, line-by-line at this point.

Comment: I've got it. The problem wasn't with RSQLite but with the tool I was using to check status and delete records (SQLPro for SQLite). For whatever reason, deletes made through the tool cleared them from the on-screen display—and count()—but must have left the records physically in the database. When records are added and deleted strictly in R code with RSQLite, all is well. Thanks for being a sounding board, @DinoCoderSaurus.

Comment: Good on ya, I'm glad you got it sorted.